# Parser for a log file

Tags: python, parsing

I wrote a parser to extract data from a log file. The file format is a bit irregular, and so is also the parser code, as it turned out. It is a clutter of different loop types, different ways to iterate, and different ways of treating strings:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys

logfilename = sys.argv[1]
csvfilename = os.path.splitext(logfilename)[0] + '.csv'

step = 0
data = []

logfile = open(logfilename,'r')

def match_step(line):
    return re.match(r'\.step (.*)', line)

# find first .step definition
for line in logfile:    
    match = match_step(line)
    if match:
        break

# iterate through all steps with parameters
while match:
    step += 1
    row = { 'step': int(step) }

    parameters = match.group(1).split()
    for p in parameters:
        [key, value] = p.split('=')
        row[key] = float(value)

    data.append(row)
    match = match_step(next(logfile))

# iterate through measurement definitions
for line in logfile:    
    match = re.match(r'Measurement: (.*)', line)
    if match:  
        name = match.group(1)
        next(logfile) # skip row with column details

        # iterate through measurement results for each step
        while True:
            measurement = next(logfile).split()
            if not measurement:
                break
            row = { 'step': int(measurement[0]), name: float(measurement[1]) }
            data.append(row)

logfile.close()

frame = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('step').groupby('step').first()
frame.to_csv(csvfilename)
```

What could I do to improve code readability and consistency, especially in the parsing portion of the code?

I do not really care about performance since the process to generate the original log file already takes some minutes.

This is an example log file:

```
Circuit: * D:\LTSpice\loss.asc

m1:1:v_sm: Missing value, assumed 0V @ DC
Per .tran options, skipping operating point for transient analysis.
.step iload=10 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=20 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=30 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=40 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=50 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=60 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=70 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=80 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=90 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=100 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=110 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=120 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=130 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=140 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=150 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=160 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=170 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=180 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=190 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=200 vdc=36 rg=1
.step iload=10 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=20 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=30 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=40 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=50 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=60 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=70 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=80 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=90 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=100 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=110 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=120 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=130 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=140 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=150 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=160 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=170 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=180 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=190 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=200 vdc=40 rg=1
.step iload=10 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=20 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=30 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=40 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=50 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=60 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=70 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=80 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=90 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=100 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=110 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=120 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=130 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=140 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=150 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=160 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=170 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=180 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=190 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=200 vdc=44 rg=1
.step iload=10 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=20 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=30 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=40 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=50 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=60 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=70 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=80 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=90 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=100 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=110 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=120 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=130 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=140 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=150 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=160 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=170 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=180 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=190 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=200 vdc=48 rg=1
.step iload=10 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=20 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=30 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=40 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=50 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=60 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=70 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=80 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=90 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=100 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=110 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=120 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=130 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=140 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=150 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=160 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=170 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=180 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=190 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=200 vdc=52 rg=1
.step iload=10 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=20 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=30 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=40 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=50 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=60 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=70 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=80 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=90 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=100 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=110 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=120 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=130 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=140 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=150 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=160 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=170 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=180 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=190 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=200 vdc=56 rg=1
.step iload=10 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=20 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=30 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=40 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=50 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=60 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=70 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=80 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=90 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=100 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=110 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=120 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=130 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=140 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=150 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=160 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=170 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=180 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=190 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=200 vdc=36 rg=2
.step iload=10 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=20 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=30 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=40 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=50 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=60 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=70 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=80 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=90 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=100 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=110 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=120 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=130 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=140 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=150 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=160 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=170 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=180 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=190 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=200 vdc=40 rg=2
.step iload=10 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=20 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=30 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=40 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=50 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=60 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=70 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=80 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=90 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=100 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=110 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=120 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=130 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=140 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=150 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=160 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=170 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=180 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=190 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=200 vdc=44 rg=2
.step iload=10 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=20 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=30 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=40 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=50 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=60 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=70 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=80 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=90 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=100 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=110 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=120 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=130 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=140 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=150 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=160 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=170 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=180 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=190 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=200 vdc=48 rg=2
.step iload=10 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=20 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=30 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=40 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=50 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=60 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=70 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=80 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=90 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=100 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=110 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=120 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=130 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=140 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=150 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=160 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=170 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=180 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=190 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=200 vdc=52 rg=2
.step iload=10 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=20 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=30 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=40 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=50 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=60 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=70 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=80 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=90 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=100 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=110 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=120 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=130 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=140 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=150 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=160 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=170 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=180 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=190 vdc=56 rg=2
.step iload=200 vdc=56 rg=2


Measurement: eon
  step  INTEG(v(drain)*ix(m1:d))    FROM    TO
     1  1.82588e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
     2  4.17134e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
     3  7.00321e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
     4  1.03301e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
     5  1.41369e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
     6  1.84238e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
     7  2.32117e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
     8  2.84883e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
     9  3.42491e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    10  4.04575e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    11  4.71822e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    12  5.43457e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    13  6.20163e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    14  7.01661e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    15  7.87419e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    16  8.7822e-005 1e-005  1.02e-005
    17  9.73496e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    18  0.000107334 1e-005  1.02e-005
    19  0.00011775  1e-005  1.02e-005
    20  0.000128672 1e-005  1.02e-005
    21  2.01474e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
    22  4.58268e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
    23  7.67373e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
    24  1.13006e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    25  1.54471e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    26  2.01132e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    27  2.53309e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    28  3.10536e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    29  3.73023e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    30  4.41231e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    31  5.14188e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    32  5.92874e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    33  6.75954e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    34  7.64433e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    35  8.58157e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    36  9.57088e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    37  0.000106059 1e-005  1.02e-005
    38  0.000116983 1e-005  1.02e-005
    39  0.000128391 1e-005  1.02e-005
    40  0.000140257 1e-005  1.02e-005
    41  2.19203e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
    42  4.97675e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
    43  8.3144e-006 1e-005  1.02e-005
    44  1.22347e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    45  1.66951e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    46  2.17464e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    47  2.73532e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    48  3.35368e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    49  4.02896e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    50  4.75927e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    51  5.55096e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    52  6.39629e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    53  7.29618e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    54  8.25448e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    55  9.26558e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    56  0.000103305 1e-005  1.02e-005
    57  0.000114593 1e-005  1.02e-005
    58  0.000126368 1e-005  1.02e-005
    59  0.000138698 1e-005  1.02e-005
    60  0.000151569 1e-005  1.02e-005
    61  2.36219e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
    62  5.35277e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
    63  8.93444e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
    64  1.31182e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    65  1.79136e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    66  2.3314e-005 1e-005  1.02e-005
    67  2.9333e-005 1e-005  1.02e-005
    68  3.59266e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    69  4.31761e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    70  5.09889e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    71  5.94634e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    72  6.84967e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    73  7.8198e-005 1e-005  1.02e-005
    74  8.84392e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    75  9.93694e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    76  0.000110811 1e-005  1.02e-005
    77  0.00012289  1e-005  1.02e-005
    78  0.000135515 1e-005  1.02e-005
    79  0.000148799 1e-005  1.02e-005
    80  0.000162664 1e-005  1.02e-005
    81  2.53127e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
    82  5.72998e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
    83  9.54195e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
    84  1.40013e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    85  1.91076e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    86  2.48313e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    87  3.12246e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    88  3.82451e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    89  4.59383e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    90  5.43192e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    91  6.32779e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    92  7.29517e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    93  8.32275e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    94  9.42133e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
    95  0.000105792 1e-005  1.02e-005
    96  0.000118051 1e-005  1.02e-005
    97  0.00013091  1e-005  1.02e-005
    98  0.000144435 1e-005  1.02e-005
    99  0.000158566 1e-005  1.02e-005
   100  0.000173324 1e-005  1.02e-005
   101  2.70084e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
   102  6.08804e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
   103  1.01309e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   104  1.48588e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   105  2.02551e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   106  2.63259e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   107  3.31072e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   108  4.05473e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   109  4.87006e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   110  5.75245e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   111  6.70787e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   112  7.7313e-005 1e-005  1.02e-005
   113  8.82438e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   114  9.98267e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   115  0.000112141 1e-005  1.02e-005
   116  0.000125152 1e-005  1.02e-005
   117  0.000138777 1e-005  1.02e-005
   118  0.000153199 1e-005  1.02e-005
   119  0.000168253 1e-005  1.02e-005
   120  0.000183974 1e-005  1.02e-005
   121  1.82588e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
   122  4.17134e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
   123  7.00321e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
   124  1.03301e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   125  1.41369e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   126  1.84238e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   127  2.32117e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   128  2.84883e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   129  3.42491e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   130  4.04575e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   131  4.71822e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   132  5.43457e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   133  6.20163e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   134  7.01661e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   135  7.87419e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   136  8.7822e-005 1e-005  1.02e-005
   137  9.73496e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   138  0.000107334 1e-005  1.02e-005
   139  0.00011775  1e-005  1.02e-005
   140  0.000128672 1e-005  1.02e-005
   141  2.01474e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
   142  4.58268e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
   143  7.67373e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
   144  1.13006e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   145  1.54471e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   146  2.01132e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   147  2.53309e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   148  3.10536e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   149  3.73023e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   150  4.41231e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   151  5.14188e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   152  5.92874e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   153  6.75954e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   154  7.64433e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   155  8.58157e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   156  9.57088e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   157  0.000106059 1e-005  1.02e-005
   158  0.000116983 1e-005  1.02e-005
   159  0.000128391 1e-005  1.02e-005
   160  0.000140257 1e-005  1.02e-005
   161  2.19203e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
   162  4.97675e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
   163  8.3144e-006 1e-005  1.02e-005
   164  1.22347e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   165  1.66951e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   166  2.17464e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   167  2.73532e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   168  3.35368e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   169  4.02896e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   170  4.75927e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   171  5.55096e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   172  6.39629e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   173  7.29618e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   174  8.25448e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   175  9.26558e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   176  0.000103305 1e-005  1.02e-005
   177  0.000114593 1e-005  1.02e-005
   178  0.000126368 1e-005  1.02e-005
   179  0.000138698 1e-005  1.02e-005
   180  0.000151569 1e-005  1.02e-005
   181  2.36219e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
   182  5.35277e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
   183  8.93444e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
   184  1.31182e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   185  1.79136e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   186  2.3314e-005 1e-005  1.02e-005
   187  2.9333e-005 1e-005  1.02e-005
   188  3.59266e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   189  4.31761e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   190  5.09889e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   191  5.94634e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   192  6.84967e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   193  7.8198e-005 1e-005  1.02e-005
   194  8.84392e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   195  9.93694e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   196  0.000110811 1e-005  1.02e-005
   197  0.00012289  1e-005  1.02e-005
   198  0.000135515 1e-005  1.02e-005
   199  0.000148799 1e-005  1.02e-005
   200  0.000162664 1e-005  1.02e-005
   201  2.53127e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
   202  5.72998e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
   203  9.54195e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
   204  1.40013e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   205  1.91076e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   206  2.48313e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   207  3.12246e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   208  3.82451e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   209  4.59383e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   210  5.43192e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   211  6.32779e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   212  7.29517e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   213  8.32275e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   214  9.42133e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   215  0.000105792 1e-005  1.02e-005
   216  0.000118051 1e-005  1.02e-005
   217  0.00013091  1e-005  1.02e-005
   218  0.000144435 1e-005  1.02e-005
   219  0.000158566 1e-005  1.02e-005
   220  0.000173324 1e-005  1.02e-005
   221  2.70084e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
   222  6.08804e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
   223  1.01309e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   224  1.48588e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   225  2.02551e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   226  2.63259e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   227  3.31072e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   228  4.05473e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   229  4.87006e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   230  5.75245e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   231  6.70787e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   232  7.7313e-005 1e-005  1.02e-005
   233  8.82438e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   234  9.98267e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
   235  0.000112141 1e-005  1.02e-005
   236  0.000125152 1e-005  1.02e-005
   237  0.000138777 1e-005  1.02e-005
   238  0.000153199 1e-005  1.02e-005
   239  0.000168253 1e-005  1.02e-005
   240  0.000183974 1e-005  1.02e-005

Measurement: eoff
  step  INTEG(v(drain)*ix(m1:d))    FROM    TO
     1  4.23893e-006    2e-005  2.02e-005
     2  6.95585e-006    2e-005  2.02e-005
     3  1.0193e-005 2e-005  2.02e-005
     4  1.3824e-005 2e-005  2.02e-005
     5  1.78051e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
     6  2.21101e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
     7  2.67549e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
     8  3.17371e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
     9  3.70578e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    10  4.277e-005  2e-005  2.02e-005
    11  4.87986e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    12  5.51665e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    13  6.19453e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    14  6.915e-005  2e-005  2.02e-005
    15  7.66868e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    16  8.46352e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    17  9.29818e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    18  0.000101657 2e-005  2.02e-005
    19  0.000110735 2e-005  2.02e-005
    20  0.000120178 2e-005  2.02e-005
    21  4.69635e-006    2e-005  2.02e-005
    22  7.69407e-006    2e-005  2.02e-005
    23  1.12591e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    24  1.52438e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    25  1.9606e-005 2e-005  2.02e-005
    26  2.43249e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    27  2.94065e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    28  3.48604e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    29  4.06825e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    30  4.69548e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    31  5.35431e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    32  6.06112e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    33  6.81013e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    34  7.60042e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    35  8.43295e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    36  9.31359e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    37  0.00010231  2e-005  2.02e-005
    38  0.000111976 2e-005  2.02e-005
    39  0.000121963 2e-005  2.02e-005
    40  0.000132423 2e-005  2.02e-005
    41  5.1599e-006 2e-005  2.02e-005
    42  8.41701e-006    2e-005  2.02e-005
    43  1.22973e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    44  1.66192e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    45  2.13463e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    46  2.64597e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    47  3.19739e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    48  3.78825e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    49  4.41972e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    50  5.09872e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    51  5.82033e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    52  6.59461e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    53  7.406e-005  2e-005  2.02e-005
    54  8.27488e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    55  9.18643e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    56  0.000101476 2e-005  2.02e-005
    57  0.000111573 2e-005  2.02e-005
    58  0.000122229 2e-005  2.02e-005
    59  0.000133124 2e-005  2.02e-005
    60  0.000144596 2e-005  2.02e-005
    61  5.63236e-006    2e-005  2.02e-005
    62  9.13522e-006    2e-005  2.02e-005
    63  1.33072e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    64  1.79548e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    65  2.30477e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    66  2.85415e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    67  3.44904e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    68  4.0866e-005 2e-005  2.02e-005
    69  4.7659e-005 2e-005  2.02e-005
    70  5.50591e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    71  6.27947e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    72  7.11432e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    73  8.00001e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    74  8.94251e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    75  9.93542e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    76  0.000109774 2e-005  2.02e-005
    77  0.00012074  2e-005  2.02e-005
    78  0.000132208 2e-005  2.02e-005
    79  0.000144181 2e-005  2.02e-005
    80  0.00015664  2e-005  2.02e-005
    81  6.10254e-006    2e-005  2.02e-005
    82  9.83685e-006    2e-005  2.02e-005
    83  1.42959e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    84  1.92432e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    85  2.4707e-005 2e-005  2.02e-005
    86  3.05967e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    87  3.69216e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    88  4.37559e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    89  5.11195e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    90  5.89263e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    91  6.734e-005  2e-005  2.02e-005
    92  7.63461e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    93  8.58748e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    94  9.60459e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
    95  0.000106726 2e-005  2.02e-005
    96  0.00011802  2e-005  2.02e-005
    97  0.000129852 2e-005  2.02e-005
    98  0.000142253 2e-005  2.02e-005
    99  0.000155198 2e-005  2.02e-005
   100  0.000168663 2e-005  2.02e-005
   101  6.5849e-006 2e-005  2.02e-005
   102  1.05374e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   103  1.52673e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   104  2.05492e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   105  2.63589e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   106  3.26249e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   107  3.93226e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   108  4.66382e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   109  5.44663e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   110  6.28883e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   111  7.18675e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   112  8.15138e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   113  9.17877e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   114  0.000102613 2e-005  2.02e-005
   115  0.000114123 2e-005  2.02e-005
   116  0.000126246 2e-005  2.02e-005
   117  0.000138925 2e-005  2.02e-005
   118  0.000152236 2e-005  2.02e-005
   119  0.000166172 2e-005  2.02e-005
   120  0.000180598 2e-005  2.02e-005
   121  4.23893e-006    2e-005  2.02e-005
   122  6.95585e-006    2e-005  2.02e-005
   123  1.0193e-005 2e-005  2.02e-005
   124  1.3824e-005 2e-005  2.02e-005
   125  1.78051e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   126  2.21101e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   127  2.67549e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   128  3.17371e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   129  3.70578e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   130  4.277e-005  2e-005  2.02e-005
   131  4.87986e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   132  5.51665e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   133  6.19453e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   134  6.915e-005  2e-005  2.02e-005
   135  7.66868e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   136  8.46352e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   137  9.29818e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   138  0.000101657 2e-005  2.02e-005
   139  0.000110735 2e-005  2.02e-005
   140  0.000120178 2e-005  2.02e-005
   141  4.69635e-006    2e-005  2.02e-005
   142  7.69407e-006    2e-005  2.02e-005
   143  1.12591e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   144  1.52438e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   145  1.9606e-005 2e-005  2.02e-005
   146  2.43249e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   147  2.94065e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   148  3.48604e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   149  4.06825e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   150  4.69548e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   151  5.35431e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   152  6.06112e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   153  6.81013e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   154  7.60042e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   155  8.43295e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   156  9.31359e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   157  0.00010231  2e-005  2.02e-005
   158  0.000111976 2e-005  2.02e-005
   159  0.000121963 2e-005  2.02e-005
   160  0.000132423 2e-005  2.02e-005
   161  5.1599e-006 2e-005  2.02e-005
   162  8.41701e-006    2e-005  2.02e-005
   163  1.22973e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   164  1.66192e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   165  2.13463e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   166  2.64597e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   167  3.19739e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   168  3.78825e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   169  4.41972e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   170  5.09872e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   171  5.82033e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   172  6.59461e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   173  7.406e-005  2e-005  2.02e-005
   174  8.27488e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   175  9.18643e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   176  0.000101476 2e-005  2.02e-005
   177  0.000111573 2e-005  2.02e-005
   178  0.000122229 2e-005  2.02e-005
   179  0.000133124 2e-005  2.02e-005
   180  0.000144596 2e-005  2.02e-005
   181  5.63236e-006    2e-005  2.02e-005
   182  9.13522e-006    2e-005  2.02e-005
   183  1.33072e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   184  1.79548e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   185  2.30477e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   186  2.85415e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   187  3.44904e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   188  4.0866e-005 2e-005  2.02e-005
   189  4.7659e-005 2e-005  2.02e-005
   190  5.50591e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   191  6.27947e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   192  7.11432e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   193  8.00001e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   194  8.94251e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   195  9.93542e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   196  0.000109774 2e-005  2.02e-005
   197  0.00012074  2e-005  2.02e-005
   198  0.000132208 2e-005  2.02e-005
   199  0.000144181 2e-005  2.02e-005
   200  0.00015664  2e-005  2.02e-005
   201  6.10254e-006    2e-005  2.02e-005
   202  9.83685e-006    2e-005  2.02e-005
   203  1.42959e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   204  1.92432e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   205  2.4707e-005 2e-005  2.02e-005
   206  3.05967e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   207  3.69216e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   208  4.37559e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   209  5.11195e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   210  5.89263e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   211  6.734e-005  2e-005  2.02e-005
   212  7.63461e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   213  8.58748e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   214  9.60459e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   215  0.000106726 2e-005  2.02e-005
   216  0.00011802  2e-005  2.02e-005
   217  0.000129852 2e-005  2.02e-005
   218  0.000142253 2e-005  2.02e-005
   219  0.000155198 2e-005  2.02e-005
   220  0.000168663 2e-005  2.02e-005
   221  6.5849e-006 2e-005  2.02e-005
   222  1.05374e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   223  1.52673e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   224  2.05492e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   225  2.63589e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   226  3.26249e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   227  3.93226e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   228  4.66382e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   229  5.44663e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   230  6.28883e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   231  7.18675e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   232  8.15138e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   233  9.17877e-005    2e-005  2.02e-005
   234  0.000102613 2e-005  2.02e-005
   235  0.000114123 2e-005  2.02e-005
   236  0.000126246 2e-005  2.02e-005
   237  0.000138925 2e-005  2.02e-005
   238  0.000152236 2e-005  2.02e-005
   239  0.000166172 2e-005  2.02e-005
   240  0.000180598 2e-005  2.02e-005


Date: Sun Sep 22 18:48:00 2019
Total elapsed time: 186.382 seconds.

tnom = 27
temp = 27
method = modified trap
totiter = 4603
traniter = 4603
tranpoints = 1964
accept = 1663
rejected = 301
matrix size = 43
fillins = 99
solver = Normal
Matrix Compiler1: 9.73 KB object code size  5.9/3.3/[0.7]
Matrix Compiler2: 5.38 KB object code size  1.4/3.0/[0.5]
```

The example log file can also be found [here](https://github.com/realtime/python-tools/blob/master/testdata/loss.log), as well as the [code](https://github.com/realtime/python-tools/blob/master/ltparse.py) above, both on my GitHub.

Please note: *I am not a professional programmer*, I only write code to support my main activity which is electronics engineering.

Comment: To whoever is voting to close this question: don't forget to leave a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started reviewing this last night, and got way off track from what you need. You've been clear that this is hobbyist code that already works; the only reason you're hear asking how to improve it is (I guess) so it'll be easier for you to resume work on a year from now.

### First, some responses to your actual code:

- Breaking your code up into functions is often good, even if the function is only used once. This *can* make things more verbose, but it's worth it if it helps us understand the flow of the code, or helps us consider pieces of it in isolation.
- It's my opinion that strong [type signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5) are always a good idea. They clarify what you code does, and unlike a comment they can't be wrong.
- The example log file has less than a thousand lines. For a small enough file, it will make sense to read the whole thing into a list of strings before trying to work with it. It's more performant to work with streams than lists, but realizing that performance benefit here would be hard because we have to hold all the *data* from the first n-1 sections in memory until we get to the last section. **Until you start having performance problems, load all your data right at the beginning.**
- [List comprehensions](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html) are wonderful and cover all the basic python data structures. That said, in order for them to work for this situation you'll need some [helper functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools).
- You're writing this as a CLI tool. Using the [main-function pattern](https://www.guru99.com/learn-python-main-function-with-examples-understand-main.html) will make the code easier to play with in other contexts.

### What I wrote last night:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys
from itertools import chain, dropwhile, groupby
from typing import *

def read_lines(file_name:str) -> Iterable[str]:
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f: # This is generally preferable to closing the file manually.
        return [line.strip() for line in f]

def parse_lines(lines: Iterable[str]) -> Dict[int, Dict[str, float]]:
    runs = [
        run
        for run
        in map(lambda g: list(g[1]), groupby(lines, bool))
        # filter out the headers, footers, and empty lines:
        if any(l.startswith('.step') or l.startswith('Measurement:') for l in run)
    ]
    steps = {
        step_number: read_step(line)
        for (step_number, line)
        in enumerate(
            dropwhile(lambda l: not l.startswith('.step'),
                      runs[0]),
            1)
    }
    metrics = {
        read_measurment_key(measurment_batch[0]): {
            int(step_number): float(measurement)
            for [step_number, measurement]
            in map(lambda m: m.split()[0:2], measurment_batch[2:])
        }
        for measurment_batch in runs[1:]
    }
    return {
        step_number: dict(chain(
            step.items(),
            (
                (measurment_key, measurments[step_number])
                for (measurment_key, measurments)
                in metrics.items()
            )
        ))
        for (step_number, step) in steps.items()
    }

def read_step(line: str) -> Dict[str, float]:
    match = re.match(r'\.step (.*)', line) # For performance we could compile the regex.
    return {
        key: float(value)
        for [key, value]
        in map(
            lambda parameter: parameter.split('='),
            match.group(1).split()
        )
    }

def read_measurment_key(line: str) -> str:
    match = re.match(r'Measurement: (.*)', line) # For performance we could compile the regex.
    return match.group(1)

def main():
    logfilename = 'loss.log' # Or read the argument as you did.
    csvfilename = os.path.splitext(logfilename)[0] + '.csv'

    log_file_lines = read_lines(logfilename)
    data = parse_lines(log_file_lines)
    frame = pd.DataFrame(
        dict(step = step_number, **values)
        for (step_number, values) in data.items()
    ).set_index('step')

    frame.to_csv(csvfilename)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

### Is that better?

I don't know.

- Is it readable to you? It sounds like you probably don't already know most of the syntax used, and there's probably only so much new stuff you'll want to learn for this project.
- When you need to update it a year from now, will it be clear what the current `runs = [...]` section is doing? Will you be able to make the needed changes with minimal trial and error?
- Does it actually work? I know it *runs*, and the output *looks* the same, but how do we know I didn't introduce some small bug such that 5% of your data is now wrong?
- How will it handle bad data? I didn't put in any kind of error detection.

### What's good about it?

- The use of typed functions will help us be sure the code is doing what we intend it to do. I could actually have taken this further by moving *more* stuff out into individual functions.
- The use of list comprehensions and other "functional programming" styles means that we're never mutating the state of a variable. This also helps us be sure everything is working as intended.
- The use of [pure functions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-functions/) also helps us be sure everything is working as intended.
- Basically every "line" can be read as "build a value", and the nature of those values is clearly (?) indicated by the names of the variables we assigning to or the functions we're returning from.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. I will see how I can benefit from it and then get back. Some remarks: You write it is "hobbyist code". This is almost certainly true regarding my skill level, but nevertheless this code was created for a professional purpose, just in a different domain. Also, looking at your code (and that of @Reinderien) I realize that there is one feature in my original code I like: It follows the sequence of the original log file. In 80% of usage I actually read the log file and do not use the parser. That makes it easy to retrace what the parser is doing.

Comment: Interesting. I guess the (structured, explicit) way to implement that way of thinking would be a "Builder" pattern: A class that sets up an empty data structure (possibly a data-frame, possibly something custom) on `__init__()`, and then exposes a (stateful) `ingest(self, line:str)` function and some kind of final-output function. But really it's not clear what would make one implementation better than another for you.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote an example of what you can do to clean this up:

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict
from csv import DictWriter
from os.path import splitext
from sys import argv
from typing import Iterable


def get_measure_matches(log: str) -> tuple:
    return tuple(re.finditer(r'Measurement: (.*)$', log, re.M))


def parse_main(log: str, measure_matches: tuple) -> (list, OrderedDict):
    all_cols = OrderedDict((('step', None),))
    rows = []
    main_row_re = re.compile(r'(\S+)=(\S+)')
    main_lines = log[:measure_matches[0].start()].splitlines()
    step = 1
    for line in main_lines:
        row = {}
        for match in main_row_re.finditer(line):
            k, v = match.groups()
            all_cols[k] = None
            row[k] = v
        if row:
            row['step'] = step
            rows.append(row)
            step += 1

    for m in measure_matches:
        all_cols[m[1]] = None

    return rows, all_cols


def parse_measures(log: str, measure_matches: tuple, rows: Iterable[dict]):
    measure_ends = (*(m.start() for m in measure_matches[1:]), -1)

    measure_re = re.compile(r'^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)', re.M)
    for measure, measure_end in zip(measure_matches, measure_ends):
        measure_name = measure[1]
        blob = log[measure.end(): measure_end]

        for match in measure_re.finditer(blob):
            try:
                step, val = match.groups()
                rows[int(step) - 1][measure_name] = float(val)
            except ValueError:
                pass


def write_csv(rows: Iterable[dict], cols: Iterable[str], csv_filename: str):
    """
    step,iload,vdc,rg,eon,eoff
    1,10.0,36.0,1.0,1.82588e-06,4.23893e-06
    2,20.0,36.0,1.0,4.17134e-06,6.95585e-06
    (etc)
    """
    with open(csv_filename, 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = DictWriter(csv_file, cols)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(rows)


def main():
    log_filename = argv[1]
    with open(log_filename) as log_file:
        log = log_file.read()

    measure_matches = get_measure_matches(log)
    rows, all_cols = parse_main(log, measure_matches)

    parse_measures(log, measure_matches, rows)

    csv_filename = splitext(log_filename)[0] + '.csv'
    write_csv(rows, all_cols.keys(), csv_filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Notes:

- There are methods
- No need to use pandas - this runs on base Python 3
- Better use of `finditer`
- Type hints
- No need to call `group(n)`
- Implicitly close files in a context manager

Answer (score 3):

The log file looks like it is made up of bunch of sections separated by blank lines.  So, an approach is to code functions to parse each section. The main driver can scan the log file to find the sections and then pass the parsing off to the parsing functions.  The parsing functions have a common interface, to make it easy to add new parsing functions.

The code below is mostly comments and doc strings.

This is the driver.  It iterates over the lines in the log file, trying to identify what kind of section it's reading.  For example, if a line starts with '.step' it is in the 'step' section, etc.

```
def parse_log(lines):
    """
    Parses a log file in which sections are delimited by blank lines.

    Input 'lines' is an iterable over the lines of the log file.
    Output is a defaultdict of dictionaries.  The defaultdict is keyed by
    step number. The dict for each step is a dict of the parameters and 
    measurements associated with that step:

        defaultdict(dict,
                    {1: {'step': 1, 'iload': '10', 'vdc': '36', 'rg': '1',
                         'eon': '1.82588e-006', 'eoff': '4.23893e-006'},
                     2: {'step': 2, 'iload': '20', 'vdc': '36', 'rg': '1',
                         'eon': '4.17134e-006', 'eoff': '6.95585e-006'},
                     3: {'step': 3, 'iload': '30', 'vdc': '36', 'rg': '1',
                         'eon': '7.00321e-006', 'eoff': '1.0193e-005'},
                      ...
                      })
    """

    # Lines in the input are checked to see if the section can be identified.  If a section is
    # identified a section specific parsing function is called. If a section cannot be identified
    # from a line, the line is appended to 'leadin'.
    #
    # Some sections are easier to identify after reading a few lines.  For example, the
    # 'step' section contains lines that start with '.step'.  
    #
    #    m1:1:v_sm: Missing value, assumed 0V @ DC
    #    Per .tran options, skipping operating point for transient analysis.
    #    .step iload=10 vdc=36 rg=1
    #    .step iload=20 vdc=36 rg=1
    #    ...
    #    
    # The list of the 'leadin' lines are passed to 'section()' so that the section specific 
    # parsing function gets all of the lines in the section (e.g., the m1:1 ..., and Per ... lines
    # in the example above).    
    #
    # Section specific parsing functions are expected to return a dictionary, keyed by step number,
    # of dictionaries containing parameter or measurement names and their values. The section
    # specific dictionaries are merged and returned.

    data = defaultdict(dict)

    leadin = []
    section_data = None

    for line in lines:

        line = line.lstrip()

        if not line:
            if leadin:
                leadin = []

                # If 'leadin' is is not empty, there was an unknown or unrecognized section.
                # For debuging, it might be useful to print (or log) the first few lines.
                #print(f"unknown section: {leadin[:5]}")

            continue

        leadin.append(line)

        if line.startswith('.step'):
            section_data = parse_step_section(section(lines, leadin))

        elif line.startswith('Measurement: '):
            section_data = parse_measurement_section(section(lines, leadin))

        if section_data:
            for step,fields in section_data.items():
                data[step].update(fields)

            leadin = []
            section_data = None

    return data
```

These are the section specific parsing routines:

```
def parse_step_section(lines):
    """
    Section specific parse function for the 'step' section of a log file.

    Input 'lines' is an iterable (e.g., a file, list, etc.) over lines of the section. 

    The section looks like:

        m1:1:v_sm: Missing value, assumed 0V @ DC
        Per .tran options, skipping operating point for transient analysis.
        .step iload=10 vdc=36 rg=1
        .step iload=20 vdc=36 rg=1
        .step iload=30 vdc=36 rg=1
        .step iload=40 vdc=36 rg=1
        ...

    The '.step' lines are implicitly numbered, starting at 1.

    Output is a dict of dicts.  The outer dict is keyed by step.  The inner dicts are 
    keyed by parameter name.  Like this:

        {1: {'step': 1, 'iload': '10', 'vdc': '36', 'rg': '1'},
         2: {'step': 2, 'iload': '20', 'vdc': '36', 'rg': '1'},
         3: {'step': 3, 'iload': '30', 'vdc': '36', 'rg': '1'},
         4: {'step': 4, 'iload': '40', 'vdc': '36', 'rg': '1'},
         ...
         }

    """

    # The first two lines are skipped, because they aren't being used.
    next(lines)
    next(lines)

    pattern = re.compile(r"(\S+)=(\S+)")

    data = {}

    for step,line in enumerate(lines, 1):
        d = dict([('step',step)] + pattern.findall(line))
        data[step] = d

    return data


def parse_measurement_section(lines):
    """
    Section specific parse function for a measurement section.

    Input 'lines' is an iterable (e.g., a file, list, etc.) over lines of the section. 

    The section looks like:

        Measurement: eon
          step  INTEG(v(drain)*ix(m1:d))    FROM    TO
             1  1.82588e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
             2  4.17134e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
             3  7.00321e-006    1e-005  1.02e-005
             4  1.03301e-005    1e-005  1.02e-005
             ...

    The first line contains the name of the measurement (e.g., 'eon').
    The second line contains the header for the following table.
    The table is terminated with a blank line.

    This function only parses the first two columns and returns a dictionary like:

            {1: {'eon': '1.82588e-006'},
             2: {'eon': '4.17134e-006'},
             3: {'eon': '7.00321e-006'},
             4: {'eon': '1.03301e-005'},
             ....
             }
    """

    _, name = next(lines).strip().split()

    # skip header line
    next(lines)  

    step_meas_rest = (line.split(maxsplit=2) for line in lines)

    data = {int(step):{name:measurement} for step,measurement,_ in step_meas_rest}

    return data
```

This is a helper function.

```
def section(lines, leadin=None):
    """
    Generator that yields lines from 'leadin' then from 'lines'.  Leading blank lines are skipped.
    It terminates when a trailing blank line is read.
    """
    if leadin:
        lines = it.chain(leadin, lines)

    line = next(lines).lstrip()

    while not line:
        line = next(lines).lstrip()

    while line:
        yield line
        line = next(lines).lstrip()
```

The main program:

```
def main(log, output):
    logdata = parse_log(log)

    fieldnames = logdata[1].keys()

    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for step, stepdata in logdata.items():
        writer.writerow(stepdata)
```

Answer (score 2):

The contributed answers each had some valuable contributions, but they did not really achieve the clarity (as perceived by me) I was hoping for. I guess this was mainly due to the fact that the answers were focused very much on how to express code elegantly, but in contrast my thinking is focused on the data.

So I picked some advice from those answers, i.e.

- follow the main function convention for CLI programs
- split everything into functions
- read the file to memory at the beginning

But I also kept much of my code, which follows along very much the data as it is presented in the log file. For me, everything I take from the log file is a kind of "observation", so storing them as a list of dictionaries makes perfect sense to me and using pandas to transform all those observation in a usable shape also seems straightforward to me.

So in summary, I implemented the advice above and cleaned up my existing code a bit to make it more uniform:

````
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys

def read_log(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as logfile:
        return logfile.readlines()

def parse_steps(log):
    steps_data = []

    step_number = 0

    for line in log:
        step_definition = re.match(r'\.step (.*)', line)
        if step_definition:
            step_number += 1
            row = { 'step': step_number }
            for parameter_match in re.finditer(r'(\S+)=(\S+)', step_definition[1]):
                parameter, value = parameter_match.groups()
                row[parameter] = float(value)
            steps_data.append(row)

    return steps_data

def parse_measurements(log):
    measurements_data = []

    log_iterator = iter(log)

    while True:
        try:
            line = next(log_iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            break

        measurement_definition = re.match(r'Measurement: (\S+)', line)
        if measurement_definition:
            measurement_name = measurement_definition[1]
            next(log_iterator) # skip one line

            while True:
                line = next(log_iterator)
                if re.match(r'^\s*\n', line): # empty line
                    break

                measurement_observation = re.match(r'^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)', line)
                if measurement_observation:
                    step, value = measurement_observation.groups()
                    row = { 'step': int(step), measurement_name: float(value) }
                    measurements_data.append(row)

    return measurements_data


def main():
    logfilename = sys.argv[1]
    log = read_log(logfilename)

    steps = parse_steps(log)
    measurements = parse_measurements(log)

    csvfilename = os.path.splitext(logfilename)[0] + '.csv'

    frame = pd.DataFrame(steps + measurements).set_index('step').groupby('step').first()
    frame.to_csv(csvfilename)


if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```
````

Comment: Are you happy with this revision or would you like a review of this code?

Comment: Nice rewrite.  Clear and readable.  I would add two things: 1) in main, `if sys.argc != 1 or argv[1] in ('-h', '--help')`: print a basic help/usage message and 2) a docstring or comment for the two parsing routines to document the format of the lines they are parsing.

Comment: @dfhwze I am fine with it, but if you spot some major problem I might have introduced, let me know.